# what is <<error type>> in swift

Tags: swift

So, I see a function `func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication)` in my AppDelegate.swift, but when I `-print-ast`, I see below

`internal func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) -> <<error type>>`

What is `<<error type>>`

Comment: Can you provide a miminal Swift source file, and the exact `swiftc -print-ast` call?

Comment: It is just the standard `AppDelegate.swift` file and exact terminal call is `swiftc AppDelegate.swift -print-ast | grep ' func '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide an SDK and a target so that the compiler
finds the Swift standard library, the required frameworks (such as "UIKit") and knows how the types,
methods, etc are defined.

Example:

```
$ xcrun --sdk iphoneos swiftc -target arm64-apple-ios10.1 -print-ast AppDelegate.swift 2>/dev/null
```

Output:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain @objc internal class AppDelegate : UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  @objc internal var window: UIWindow?
  @objc internal func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]?) -> Bool
  @objc internal func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication)
  @objc internal func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication)
  @objc internal func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication)
  @objc internal func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)
  @objc internal func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication)
  @objc deinit
  @objc override internal init()
}
```

(I added `2>/dev/null` to the command line because some warnings about `'UIApplicationMain'` are printed to the standard
error, I haven't been able yet to suppress these properly.)

Comment: So, essentially - `<<error type>>` is compiler's inability to understand required frameworks?

Comment: Is it documented somewhere ?

Comment: @prabodhprakash: I *think* the `<<error type>>` is printed because without finding UIKIT, swiftc does not even know the type `UIApplication`. – The "sdk" and "target" parameters are shown if you type "xcrun -help" and "swiftc -help". I don't know if there is a good documentation with all possible values. I inspected a build log in Xcode, plus some "try and error" :)

Answer (score 1):

`<<errortype>>` is compiler's issue or bug we can say that, indicates that complier is unable to compile your current object.
This frequently faced when you use object of type AnyObject.

Clean your project will resolve your issue,
Even if Cleaning does not do the job then Close XCode once(I never neeed to close XCode for this yet)

Comment: I'm not getting any compile error. I was just checking print-ast dump and was interested in this `<<error type>>`

Comment: Yes , I am not saying that is issue in your code, I means to say it is complier's issue

Comment: its been jus 2 years of swift . Swift compiler is evolving with every version for us. Cheers to swift